# SVG line draw - using the same javascript function for multiple SVGs

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, getelementbyid

I've recently entered the world of SVG manipulation using a mixture of JS and CSS. Here I've got an SVG line as a path which is being drawn using JavaScript.

JS:

```
    function drawRoundel() {
      var path = document.getElementById("roundelPath");
      var length = path.getTotalLength();
      path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
      path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
      path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
      path.getBoundingClientRect();
      path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 3s ease-in-out';
      path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
    }
```

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 415 415" width="415" height="415">
  <path id="roundelPath" stroke-width="22" d="M181.7,265.6l84.8,123.7c-18.1,5.6-37.3,8.7-57.2,8.7c-106,0-191.9-85.9-191.9-191.9c0-45,15.5-86.3,41.4-119.1
    l0.2-0.2l128.7,187.4c21.6,27.7,54.6,38.3,89.8,38.3c67.6,0,123.1-55.5,123.1-123.2c-5.8-66.1-45.1-122.7-100.8-152.5l-0.1,0.1
    l-85.9,59.9l-0.1,0c-15.1,10.3-25,27.7-25,47.3c0,31.6,25.6,57.3,57.3,57.3c31.6,0,57.3-25.6,57.3-57.3S277.6,87,245.9,87
    c-11.8,0-23.1,3.8-32.2,9.9l-0.1,0.1L56.9,206.3"/>
</svg>
```

This works great with one instance of an SVG and a path with a id of "roundelPath" on a page but what if I want multiple instances of the SVG with different ids? I've tried to use getElementsByClassName but it complains about getTotalLength.

Hoping this is a easy fix. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is what you posted working for one element or is there something missing?

Comment: Why are you posting the code that works?  Your `getElementsByClassName()` idea should work. If it isn't, then post **that** code.  Don't forget to include a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulLeBeau The code doesn't work. That's why I didn't post a solution 26min ago with just e.g. ...display = "none"

Comment: Pass in the id as an argument to the function rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

JS:

```
    function drawRoundel(id) {
      var path = document.getElementById(id);
      var length = path.getTotalLength();
      path.style.transition = path1.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
      path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
      path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
      path.getBoundingClientRect();
      path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 3s ease-in-out';
      path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
    }
```

Call the function with different ids:

```
drawRoundel('roundelPath1');
```

or

```
drawRoundel('roundelPath2');
```